# Narrow droppable blank area on web page needed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a row of elements on a web page and I want to drop another element between any two of them. I am building it in stages so I thought the first thing would be to create a narrow area between each which when clicked would invoke js to move them along and create space for a new element. I can put an onclick event on a span which will do this but it only works if there is character in the span. I need this to work with a blank space. This is proving to be a bit intractable.

this works

```
  <span class="spacespan"data-name="d007">!</span>
```

This does not

```
  <span class="spacespan"data-name="d007"> </span>

<script>
   $('.spacespan').on('click', function() {
   $name = $(this).data('name');
    alert("Element clicked "+ $name);
   });
</script>
```

sorry. I missed out the css.

```
.spacespan {
    width:8px;
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: A span with no content has no size. You cannot click an element with no size.

Comment: for a flexible solution and circumvent the limits of inline elements you may style the span as `display: inline-block;width: 1em;height: 1em;` and control its size without sticking to its content

Comment: OK so is there a way to give it content which is invisible?

Comment: yes you can use `<span>&nbsp;</span>` for example.. but when using `display: inline-block` you can control its size via css in a more fine tuned way. `span` is by default `display: inline` instead

Comment: Thanks Diego. This works a treat. I would like to flag it as the correct answer but I cannot find that option. Can you tell me how?

Comment: @genghis no answers have been given, only comments. this is why you can't mark it as correct